# How do I create a new table with one column from another table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and am having trouble getting the syntax for this particular process right. I just want to take a column of names out of a pre-existing table and create a new one column table with that column, then select that table.

I'm getting an error that says newTable already exists.

Here's my code right now:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE newTable (name varchar(255));
    INSERT INTO newTable SELECT name FROM oldTable;
    SELECT * FROM newTable;
END
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Comment: It doesn't already exist, if I take out the line CREATE TABLE newTable (name varchar(255)); the error says newTable doesn't exist.

Comment: works like charm, you're not telling us something http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d33523/1

Comment: Try [`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Comment: another approach is to use [create table as select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: @IlyaBursov you are right, I forgot to mention this is part of a procedure that is called multiple times so after the first iteration the table does indeed exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider dropping the table first and then re-create using `CTAS` construct

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newTable ;
CREATE TABLE newTable (name varchar(255)) AS
SELECT name FROM oldTable;
```

(OR)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable (name varchar(255)) AS
SELECT name FROM oldTable;
```

Comment: I'd add `if exists` to drop or `if not exists` to create

Comment: I get the "newTable doesn't exist" error for this too.

Comment: @IlyaBursov, right ... was editing by then you commented

Comment: Edit did the trick, my original logic was flawed because this code is included in a procedure that gets called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```